# plotly grouped relative barplots

Tags: r, plotly

is it possible to create "grouped relative barplots". I know it's possible to create grouped barplots and relative barplots. But is it possible to combine both? -> Mutliple "Relative bars" per Group?

Comment: You should really provide a reproducible example of what you've tried thusfar to avoid this being a code writing request

Comment: You're right. In the meantime I discovered the abilities of subplots and I think that's what I was looking for.